# li accordion style menu in one ul with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a website that uses ruby on rails to retrieve multiple links and place them into a single ul with multiple li elements of either class 'head' or class 'link'.

I am trying to get an accordion style effect working with this, so when a user clicks on a 'head' li the subsequent child 'link' li's appear and disappear when another 'head' li is clicked.

I know about the accordion in jquery ui but I dont think thats an option with the rails code being used in the project. I'm only an intern and I'm not sure if the CTO is going to spend his time redoing his code to suit me. I'm trying my best to work with what I've got.

Example of the code:

```
<ul>
    <li class = "head">HEAD</li>
        <li class = "link">link</li>
        <li class = "link">link</li>
        <li class = "link">link</li>
    <li class = "head">HEAD</li>
        <li class = "link">link</li>
        <li class = "link">link</li>
        <li class = "link">link</li>
    <li class = "head">HEAD</li>
        <li class = "link">link</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $('li.link').hide();

    $('li.head:first-child').click(function(){
        $('li.link').slice(0, 3).slideToggle('slow');
    });
</script>
```

This is the closest I've gotten so far for the desired effect. 
I genuinely appreciate any help I get.

Comment: You might want to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this and describe what's currently happening and how that differs from what you'd like to see. It'll make it easier for people to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really got it almost quite good, but you're just targeting the click on the first `.head` instead for all of them. Than, the `.nextUntil()` method will help you target the desired elements.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/icAtucU/1/edit)

```
$('li.link').hide();

$('li.head').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.head').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

<sub>Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Further to Roko's answer, this might help with the accordion feature, collapsing any non-relevant links that are showing when a new Head is clicked on:

```
$('li.link').hide();

$('li.head').click(function(){
    // gets all the previous links and hides them
    $(this).prevAll('.link').slideUp('slow');
    // gets all the links that come after the next head, and hides them too
    var nextHead = $(this).nextAll('.head').first();
    $(nextHead).nextAll('.link').slideUp('slow');

    // toggles all the relevant links for the current head
    $(this).nextUntil('.head').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xwbrB/7/